# How to access a UI elment in custom control template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Inside this custom control's control template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomLineGraph}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">               
              <Canvas x:name"myCanvas"></Canvas>
              <Border Background="#FF0000"
                                BorderBrush="Red"
                                BorderThickness="5">

              </Border>
          </StackPanel>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

How can I access the `Canvas` from the class

```
 public class CustomLineGraph : Control
        {
           myCanvas.AddChild(obj);
        }
```

x:name doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you the Canvas Element

```
(this.Template.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement).FindName("myCanvas") as Canvas
```